# How to clone an existing View and change the format from table to CSV?

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I have managed to figure out how to Install the [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module and create a View in order to export to CSV so that I can import this into WordPress.

Someone else has already created all the Views. Here is a screenprint of how the view looks like:

[image]

What I want to achieve next is to clone these views and then convert them to CSV format from a Table format. I simply cannot see how or where this can be done.

What I am trying to do is click on the "Working Papers Other" and then clone this View. Once it is cloned I am trying to change the Format from Table to CSV.

There surely has to be a way to do this easily, else it will take an eternity to do all of these Views.

Comment: What exactly do you want to convert: the **design** (specs) of it, or only the **data** (the Views results)?

Comment: Only the data @Pierre.Vriens please

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to get you going (referring to the screenprint you added):

1. Click the drop-down list in the upper-right that says <kbd>view Working Papers Other</kbd>, where you should then see another list item with label `clone Working Papers Other`.
2. Select (click) on that list item with label `clone Working Papers Other`.
3. Note that you'll then have an extra (and same named!) button to the right (or below) the 8 buttons you already have, with the very same label <kbd>Working Papers Other</kbd>, and the newly added one will be highlighted (grey / black), and selected.
4. To improve readability, hurry to go change the line (upper-left) that says "Display name: `Working Papers Other`" (by clicking on that `Working Papers Other` link). I suggest you change the Display name to (eg) `Working Papers Other (CSV)`.
5. Change the line (upper-left) that says "Format: `Table | Settings`" (by clicking on that `Table` link). At this point you should be able to change the *style* of the view from `Table` to the Views display offered by the [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module, with label "`Data export`".
6. Tune (refine) the "`Settings`" of the `Data export` views display to fit your needs, whereas you can see how the result will look like in the *preview* near the bottom of your page.
7. Change the line (upper-middle) that says "Path: `/publications/working-pa..." (by clicking on that`Path`link). I suggest you change the path by only adding some suffix such as`-csv`.
8. Don't forget to use the <kbd>Save</kbd> button (upper-left) to permanently store the updated configuration of your view.
9. Click the button (upper-right) that says <kbd>view Working Papers Other (CSV)</kbd> (if you used my suggestiuon in item "4.") to actually view (browse) the Views result produced by the various changes described above ... *Is it a CSV file that fits your requirements?* If not: must be that you did something wrong in the steps described above ...

**Note**: If you want to become more familiar with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), checkout the (free) [set of 30 video tutorials](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/taming-the-beast-learn-views) about the Views module.